# THz time domain spectroscopy

Tags: laser, spectroscopy

Sorry! my question can be rather easy but I don't have a deep knowledge about it, in the lab there was a stage including optical sampling by laser cavity tuning and after the photoconductive antennas, there were lenses . In the detector side, we had also the reflected THz beam and I couldn't get it why? 
Here is the setup; 
[image]

Comment: I do not understand your setup. I get the tune-able cavity part. Is the beam splitter used to couple out of the cavity? Where are the beams going afterwards? You mentioned photoconductive antennas, are they iluminated with the interference of the two outputs? Please clarify the setup/question.

Comment: Sure, after the beam splitter, upper side of the beam goes to the emitter photoc. ant. which produces Thz signal  and that signal goes through the lenses and reaches to the detector p.a.  The lower side goes to the detector antenna directly to detect the signal coming from the emitter side. Basically the reason of the reflected Thz signal is the piezo stage but I cannot imagine why . and here is the output signal

Comment: http://www.menlosystems.com/assets/Uploads/OSCAT-rapid-scan-trace.jpg

Comment: What is this image showing?

Comment: detected THz signals

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure about your setup and your actual question. In the image you provided there is something fishy, the "THz" single cycle signal has a length in the order of $ms$ but it should be in the order of "ps" you might want to check what is really shown there.

Your question shows that you struggle with the basic concepts of coherent THz generation and detection. The most used techniques for THz detection is to utilize short laser pulses in the order of 100fs to take a snapshot of your electrical field strength at a defined time after creation of the THz pulse. As the THz creation and detection pulses are coming from the same cavity, they are phase locked. This means by changing the arrival time of the sensing pulse (done by the piezo stage) you are able to step-wise measure the field strength of the THz pulse.

As detection method EOS (electro optical sampling) and photoconductive detection are the most common ones. These methods are the vehicle to utilize the sensing laser pulse in order to really measure the optical field strength. EOS uses the Pockel effect whereas photoconductive detection measures the voltage created by the THz pulse in the sensing antenna array.

Here are some additional resources which might be helpful

- [Terahertz Sources and Detectors, paragraph  2.5.1](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461418207-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1326637-p174243177)
- [Electro-optic Sampling](https://www.rp-photonics.com/electro_optic_sampling.html)
- [Introduction to terahertz science and technology](https://www-thz.physics.ox.ac.uk/spectrometer/)